# Appending data along with form data not working in jquery ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Here is my ajax call where i used the extra fields along with the form data

```
function paging(div_id, module, page_value)
{           
    var active_customer_list = $("#active_customer_list").val();
    $("#"+div_id).html(loader);   
    var data = $('#search_form').serializeArray();    
    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "my_page.php",
           data: new FormData($('#search_form')[0]).append ({ 'type' , 'paging'}),
        success: function(msg)
           {
                msg = msg.replace(/^[\s]+/g,"");
                $("#"+div_id).html(msg);                
           }
         });
    return false;       
}
```

Here i get the form data if i didnot append the values. If i append the values using append(), i just get the append values alone.

Comment: Syntax for `new FormData`  => `new FormData(someFormElement)`...Check console for errors...

Comment: There is no syntax error. I used the search_form in FormData

Comment: console `$('#search_form')[0]).append ({ 'type' , 'paging'}`

Comment: try this before send req------> data .push({ 'type' , 'paging'});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
var data = $(this).serializeArray();
data.push({name: 'cat_name', value: $('#cat_name').val()});
```

So, you must be change in your code

> `data.push({ type: 'paging' });`

Answer (score 0):

> Try this push value before send request.

```
function paging(div_id, module, page_value)
{           
    var active_customer_list = $("#active_customer_list").val();
    $("#"+div_id).html(loader);   
    var data = $('#search_form').serializeArray();   
    data .push({ 'type' , 'paging'}); 
    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "my_page.php",
           data: data,
           success: function(msg)
           {
                msg = msg.replace(/^[\s]+/g,"");
                $("#"+div_id).html(msg);                
           }
         });
    return false;       
}
```